# Nginx Magento configuration index.php cyclic error

Tags: magento, nginx

I'm trying to setup Magento on Nginx but keep getting the following error

*41 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.php"

My configuration file for this domain is as follows, I have replaced my domain with DOMAIN.info

I've also commented out some parts related to SSL since I don't have SSL setup yet

Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
server {
# Listen on port 80 as well as post 443 for SSL connections.
listen 80;
listen 443 default ssl;

server_name DOMAIN.info www.DOMAIN.info;

# Specify path to your SSL certificates.
#ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.crt;
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.key;

# Path to the files in which you wish to
# store your access and error logs.
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

# If the site is accessed via yourdomain.com
# automatically redirect to www.yourdomain.com.
if ($host = 'DOMAIN.info' ) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.DOMAIN.info/$1permanent;
}

root usr/share/nginx/www;

location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}

# Deny access to specific directories no one
# in particular needs access to anyways.
location /app/ { deny all; }
location /includes/ { deny all; }
location /lib/ { deny all; }
location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
location /var/ { deny all; }

# Allow only those who have a login name and password
# to view the export folder. Refer to /etc/nginx/htpassword.
location /var/export/ {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    autoindex on;
}

# Deny all attempts to access hidden files
# such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...
location ~ /\. {
     deny all;
     access_log off;
     log_not_found off;
}

# This redirect is added so to use Magentos
# common front handler when handling incoming URLs.
location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

# Forward paths such as /js/index.php/x.js
# to their relevant handler.
location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

# Handle the exectution of .php files.
location ~ .php$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite / /index.php last;
    }
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

My nginx.conf file looks like this

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 5;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;



events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # SSL Support
    ##

    map $scheme $fastcgi_https {
    default off;
        https on;
    }

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem is missing "/" in

> ```
> root usr/share/nginx/www;
> ```

and the fact that your config indeed creates infinite loop if /index.php can't be found:

> ```
> location ~ .php$ { 
>     if (!-e $request_filename) { 
>         rewrite / /index.php last; 
>     }
>     ...
> ```

Note that request to /index.php will be redirected to /index.php if `-e $request_filename` test fails. The request will be again matched by the same location, test will fail again and so on - till nginx will notice there are too many internal redirects and abort request processing with the above error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually found the missing slash before you answered, but I didn't spot your second point, can you tell me what `-e $request_filename` means?  I did not write this config I am still learning

Comment: It tests if the file in question exists, see [docs](http://nginx.org/r/if) for details.